# Easiest quickest language to learn for making web apps?

Tags: web-applications

For storing data do I need to know mySQL regardless of what language I choose to make web apps?

EDIT - for example, a web app like a todo list.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what type of web applications you are interesting in making?

Answer (score 0):

No, there are other options. You could use ORM's and NoSQL databases. But without knowing **SQL** it is hard to understand other technologies.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to know MySQL; [postgresql](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postgresql) is another fine choice for relational database backend storage. [Mnesia](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html) is a nice database for soft-realtime non-relational backend storage. [CouchDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Couchdb) is another non-relational database optimized for storing [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) documents that can be searched using JavaScript.

You might not even need a database at all, if on-disk file storage is good enough (see [Maildir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maildir) for an excellent mail storage mechanism).

Comment: mySQL, postgreSQL, MSSQL - have similar syntax so if the O.P is unwilling to learn mySQL I doubt he would want to learn postgreSQL (for the same reasons - whatever they are).

Answer (score 0):

No - but given that it is very easy to construct basic SQL statements you really should take the time to learn how to CRUD a databse and perform some basic joins. If you are unable to write/understand SQL I would worry about the code you are producing in the rest of your application. The http://forums.mysql.com/ as well as this site (obviously) can help you fill in the gaps in your knowledge (providing you are willing to help yourself).

Eventually you may wish to use other solutions for storing your data - an ORM or similar, however these are simply abstracting the SQL, and you would still have to understand basic database architecture in order to use those system effictively.

Finally you may wish to use a NON Relational database system like CouchDB. This may fit with your application - although I would say that using a traditional database would be greatly prefertypeable if you are just starting to learn how to code web applications.

Answer (score 0):

Languages you need to know for making web-apps are:

- Some server side language: php,
  python, ruby, java....
- Client side language: javascript
- For styling your web app: css
- Data storage: SQL

Answer (score 0):

MySQL isn't a language; it's a database that uses a reasonably good implementation of SQL.

Knowing SQL won't help you with many other languages, either... try going from SQL to Scala. Or Lisp. Or (pick randomly from [a good list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages)).

The language skills that will help the most with Web programming are definitely those for standard English. After that, Python and PHP would be at the top of my "easiest quickest language...for Web apps" list.

As always, Google is your friend, as are [the Python docs](http://docs.python.org/), [the PHP docs](http://php.net/docs.php) and sites like [PHPTutorials.org](http://phptutorials.org/).

Comment: To be fair: O.P does specifically say 'for storing data'